# How do I Make label visible before a heavy method is called

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, synchronization, async-await

I have a method that takes a few seconds to execute. I created also a big label that should appear right before the method is called and disappear when the method is finished to execute. However, my label doesn't appear even though the line that makes the label appear is placed before the method call. Why does my C# WPF code do that? How to fix this, so that my label appears before calling the method and disappears afterwards?

This is a sample of my code:

```
label.Visibility = Visible;
myMethod();
label.Visibility = Invisible;
```

Comment: when you are adding the content to that label? during run time?

Comment: Label is made upon start of the application.

Comment: Try once by making label.refresh() after making visible and before calling method.

Comment: there is no such method.

Answer (score 7):

> I have a method that takes a few seconds to execute.

Then you shouldn't do that in the UI thread, basically. That blocks the UI thread, preventing the UI from updating.

You should perform long-running tasks in other threads, but make sure you only touch the UI itself from the UI thread.

With C# 5's `async/await` functionality, this is *relatively* straightforward:

```
// This now needs to be in an async method
label.Visibility = Visible;
await Task.Run(() => myMethod());
label.Visibility = Invisible;
```

Comment: How do I declare `private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)` to be async?

Comment: @Stein: You change it to `private async void ...`. But you should really read up on `async` before you start to use it.

Comment: I get error: `Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

Comment: @Stein: Well which version of Visual Studio are you using? As per my answer, this requires C# 5 - i.e. Visual Studio 2012 or higher.

Comment: oh, okay... I am using VS2010. How to do this in this version?

Comment: @Stein: Well personally I'd look into upgrading to more a recent version of Visual Studio :) But otherwise, you'll have to use the `Dispatcher` to marshall back to the UI thread at the end of `myMethod`. You could potentially still use the TPL to start the task and then add a continuation, as a slightly cleaner approach. Of course, that depends on you running against a version of the framework that supports the TPL...